# printf format depending on number of parameters

Tags: bash, text-formatting, function

I am writing a bash function that takes a number of strings, with
each string to be printed it a separate line.

But have to compose the `frmt` variable to `printf` appropriately depending
on the number of strings being passed to the function.

```
print ()
{
  case $1 in
    h|-h|-\?|--help)
      printf "Prints a text string.\n"
      printf "\$1 TEXT  Sentence to print.\n"
      local -r f=0
      ;;
    *)
      local -r f=1
      ;;
  esac

  local -r frmt="%s\n"
  printf $frmt "$@"
}
```

Had the idea of repeating a string by the number of function argumunts using `printf`, but was not successful

```
local -r frmt=$(printf '%s\n' $(seq $#))
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify the format string? `printf(1)` automatically repeats the format as needed to match the data argument(s), rather like FORTRAN formatted I/O but without the auto-advance aka 'slash'. See [e.g. the GNU info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html#printf-invocation)

Comment: Thought to make `frmt` te be a repetition  of `%s\n` depending on the number of text parameters passed to the function.  Do not know about fortran.  Can you show me how it works if I want each parameter to be printed on a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to build a format string according to number of arguments.

To quote [the link](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html#printf-invocation) by Mr. Thompson:

> - The *format* argument is ***reused as necessary*** to convert all the given arguments. For example, the command `‘printf %s a b’` outputs `‘ab’`.

## Write test code.

When working with things like this, break it down as much you can, an build up form there. For example in your case:

## TESTING

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -

test1() {
    printf 'test1\n'
    printf 'ARG: "%s"\n' "$@"
}
test2() {
    printf 'test2\n'
    shift
    printf 'ARG: "%s"\n' "$@"
}
test3() {
    printf 'test3\n'
    printf '2-ARGS: "%s" "%s"\n' "$@"
}

test1 first a b "c d e"
printf '\n'
test2 first a b "c d e"
printf '\n'
test3 a b c d e
```

## RESULT

```
test1
ARG: "first"
ARG: "a"
ARG: "b"
ARG: "c d e"

test2
ARG: "a"
ARG: "b"
ARG: "c d e"

test3
2-ARGS: "a" "b"
2-ARGS: "c" "d"
2-ARGS: "e" ""
```

This should give an idéa

---

## The printf '%s\n' $(seq $#)

```
local -r frmt=$(printf '%s\n' $(seq $#))
```

This would result in, for example:

```
printf '%s\n' $(seq 3)
1
2
3
```

---

As always: break down what you test to the lowest component, here: `printf '%s\n' $(seq $#)` (or really `seq $#`) - and test in out in shell.